# How to approach on this - finding minimum distance of point on the ellipse from the centre of it.

Tags: analytic-geometry, self-learning, conic-sections

**Question**

*The minimum distance of any point on the ellipse $$x^2+3y^2+4xy=4$$ from its centre is ______.*

**Attempt**

Converted the given expression into $$(x+2y)^2-y^2=4$$. But, this becomes equation of hyperbola of the form $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$.

Then how it is ellipse?

Any hints or suggestion?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87265/discussion-on-question-by-jayant98-how-to-approach-on-this-finding-minimum-dis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quadratic form is
$$ x^2 + 4xy + 3 y^2 = (x+y)(x+3y) $$
The lines that approximate the hyperbola far from the origin are thus $x+y = 0$ and $x+3y = 0.$ These have two angle bisectors, which need a bit of work to find. One angle bisector gives the nearest point to the origin, where it intersects your conic $x^2 + 4xy+3y^2 = 4.$ The other angle bisector does not intersect the conic

Let's see, the bisector that does intersect the conic is also the bisector of the lines $y=x$ and $y=3x$ that stays in the first quadrant, meaning positive slope. We have lines with slopes $\tan A = 1$ and $ \tan B = 3.$ The trig formula for the bisecting angle  is just
$$ \tan \left( \frac{A+B}{2} \right) = \frac{\sin A + \sin B}{\cos A + \cos B} $$

Answer (score 1):

The matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
$$
defining the hyperbola $(x,y)B(x,y)^T=4$ has eigenvalues $2\pm\sqrt 5$. The eigenvector associated to the positive eigenvalue is $(\sqrt5-1,2)$. Therefore the vertices are obtained by solving
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x^2+4xy+3y^2=4 \\
(x,y) = t(\sqrt5-1,2) \\
\end{array}\right.
$$
The solutions are
$$
x_0 = \sqrt{\frac{14}{\sqrt{5
   }}-6}
\qquad
y_0 = \sqrt{\frac{6}{\sqrt{
   5}}-2}
$$
and the opposite point $-(x_0,y_0)$.

Therefore the distance from the center (which is the origin) is
$$
|(x_0,y_0)| = \sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2} = 2 \sqrt{\sqrt5-2} .
$$